# The command or action 'TransferText' isn't available now

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've a bunch of folders with one .accdb DB in each folder. I want to export a number of tables from them to delimited text. The tables are specified in the array `arr`.

```
Sub ExtractDBs(tableList as String)

Dim objAccess As Access.Application
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim fp As String
Dim fso As Object
Dim fsoFolder As Object, fsoSubFolder As Object, fsoFolders As Object
Dim fsoFiles As Object, fsoFile As Object
Dim x As Integer
Dim txtStream As Object
Dim arr() as string

Set objAccess = New Access.Application
    
arr = Split(tableList, ";")
fp = "\\SomeFilePath"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder(fp)
Set fsoFolders = fsoFolder.SubFolders

For Each fsoSubFolder In fsoFolders

    Set fsoFiles = fsoSubFolder.Files
    
    For Each fsoFile In fsoFiles
    
        Set db = objAccess.DBEngine.OpenDatabase(fsoFile.Path, False, True, ";PWD=SomePassword")
        
        For x = 0 To UBound(arr) - 1
            objAccess.DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, TableName:=arr(x), _
                  Filename:=fp & "\" & Replace(fsoFile.Name, ".accdb", "") & "\" & arr(x) & ".txt", _
                  HasFieldNames:=True
        Next x
        
        db.Close
        
    Next fsoFile
    
Next fsoSubFolder

objAccess.Quit
Set objAccess = Nothing

End Sub
```

The line beginning `objAccess.DoCmd.TransferText` yields the error

> The command or action 'TransferText' isn't available now.

...Which is pretty useless. I can't find an explanation online of what is required to resolve this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't actually opened any database.

`Application.OpenCurrentDatabase` opens a database in the current Access application.

`Application.DbEngine.OpenDatabase` opens a database using the database engine of the current Access application, but doesn't actually open it in the application.

So, use the following:

```
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase fsoFile.Path, False, "SomePassword"
```

Comment: After fixing that issue, use acExportDelim (instead of acImportDelim) to export Access table to CSV.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Ok, this is weird, I get a compile error on `objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase`, though it's clearly a member of the Access object and all params are in the expected format. The error is 'Expected function or variable'. Any ideas?

Comment: @HansUp Good spot

Comment: @Absinthe Apologies, remove the `Set db =`. It's a sub, not a function.

Comment: Thanks Erik, all good now. To clarify for others arriving here as this isn't intuitive - you don't actually need a DB object to export, it's a method of the application object, you create a new Access app to open the DB